# django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist by testing django form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-testing

I have the following model:

```
class Damage(models.Model):
    kind = models.ForeignKey(Kind, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def clean(self):
        if self.region not in self.kind.regions.all():
            raise ValidationError('not possible')
```

and the corresponding form:

```
class DamageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Damage
        fields = ['kind', 'region']
```

when I run the following tests, I always get the `django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: Damage has no region` failure.

```
def test_empty_input(self):
    data = {
        'kind': None,
        'region': None,
    }
    form = DamageForm(data)
    self.assertFalse(form.is_valid())

def test_invalid_input(self):
    data = {
        'kind': self.test_kind,
        'region': self.test_region,
    }
    form = DamageForm(data)
    self.assertFalse(form.is_valid())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the `region_id` and `self.kind_id` are not `None` before trying to access `self.region` or `self.kind` in your `clean` method.

```
def clean(self):
    if self.region_id is not None self.kind_id is not None and self.region not in self.kind.regions.all():
        raise ValidationError('not possible')
```

Comment: ok, that let the tests run successfully and `self.region_id is not None` is the important part. It also runs successfully if I don't use the `self.kind_id` part. But how I have to create the regions that it also works without this addition?

Comment: You need to check `self.kind_id is not None` to prevent errors when you submit `data = {'kind': None, 'region': self.test_region}`. I don't understand your question "how I have to create the regions that it also works without this addition".